# probability mass function of $Y-X$ (two Poisson random variables)

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

It is question 55 on page 86 from Ross's book(Introduction to Probability Theory)

Suppose that the joint probability mass function of $X$ and $Y$ is

$$ P(X = i, Y = j) = {j\choose i} e^{-2\lambda} \frac{\lambda^j}{j!}, \quad 0\le i\le j$$

(a) Find the probability mass function of $Y$

(b) Find the probability mass function of $X$

(c) Find the probability mass function of $Y - X$

My answers:

(b): $f_Y(j) = e^{-2\lambda} {(2\lambda)}^j/j!$

(a): $f_X(j) = e^{-\lambda} \lambda^j/j!$

for (c): to calculate $P\{Y - X = n\}$

suppose $x = k,$ $y = n + k,$

then

\begin{align}
P\{Y - X = n\} & = P\{x = k, Y = n + k\} = P(X = k) P(Y = n + k) \\[10pt]
& = \sum_{k=0}^n \left(e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} \cdot e^{-2\lambda}  \frac{(2\lambda)^{n+k}}{(n+k)!}\right)
\end{align}

then I was stuck here.

Thanks in advance

**Update 1**: follow the suggestions by @Michael Hardy

1. P( Y-X|Y ) = P(X|Y): **Calculate this first(Why???)**

Intuitively, Y - X and X complement each other when Y is given.
$$ P(X = i |Y = j) = \sum_{j=0} {j\choose i} e^{-2\lambda} \frac{\lambda^j}{j!}$$  $$ =e^{-2\lambda}\frac{\lambda^j}{j!} \sum_{j=0} {j\choose i} $$

$$ P(Y-X=j-i |Y=j) = \sum_{j=0} {j\choose j-i} e^{-2\lambda} \frac{\lambda^j}{j!}$$  $$ =e^{-2\lambda}\frac{\lambda^j}{j!} \sum_{j=0} {j\choose j-i} $$

2. Calculate P(Y-X).

suppose Y - X = n, x = i
P(Y-X = n) = $$ \sum_{i=0}^n {i+n\choose i} e^{-2\lambda} \frac{\lambda^{i+n}}{(i+n)!} $$

= $$e^{-2\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{n}}{n!} \sum_{i=0}^n\frac{\lambda^i}{i!} $$

= $$e^{-2\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{n}}{n!} e^{\lambda} $$

= $$e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{n}}{n!} $$

it is the same as @Mohit 's result.

Comment: P(X=k, Y=n+k) = P(X=k) P(Y=n+k) needs X,Y to be independent, i.e. P(X=i, Y=j) = P(X=i) P(Y=j). Is this the case?

Comment: @Batman Actually, I am not sure about that.

Comment: It might be easier to think about (1) what is the conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y$, and then (2) what is the conditional distribution of $Y-X$ given $Y$, and then look again at the marginal distribution of $X$.

Comment: Instead of $P\{Y - X = n\}  = P\{x = k, Y = n + k\} \vphantom{\dfrac11}$ you should have $\displaystyle P\{Y - X = n\}  = \sum_k P\{x = k, Y = n + k\}.$ And also, $X$ and $Y$ are not independent, according to the probability mass function that you've given, since $P(X\le Y) = 1. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yes, another formula mistake. I noticed the constraint 0≤i≤j, but not sure how to handle it.

Comment: @kimchilover you are right. I will try figure it out.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skellam_distribution

Answer (score 2):

$$\Pr(X = i, Y = j) = {j\choose i} e^{-2\lambda} \frac{\lambda^j}{j!}, \quad 0\le i\le j$$

\begin{align}
\Pr(Y=j) = {} & \sum_{i=0}^j \Pr(X=i\ \&\ Y=j) \\[10pt]
= {} & \sum_{i=0}^j \binom j i e^{-2\lambda} \frac{\lambda^j}{j!}. \\
& \text{In this sum, everything to the right of $\dbinom j i$ does} \\
& \text{not change as $i$ goes from $0$ to $j$. Therefore it can} \\
& \text{be pulled out:} \\[10pt]
= {} & e^{-2\lambda} \frac{\lambda^j}{j!} \sum_{i=0}^j \binom j i \\[10pt]
= {} & e^{-2\lambda} \frac{\lambda^j}{j!} \cdot 2^j \text{ by the binomial theorem} \\[10pt]
= {} & e^{-2\lambda} \frac{(2\lambda)^j}{j!}. \\[15pt]
\text{Therefore } Y \sim {} & \operatorname{Poisson}(2\lambda).
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\Pr(X=i) = {} & \sum_{j=i}^\infty \binom j i e^{-2\lambda} \frac{\lambda^j}{j!} \\
& \text{Notice that this sum starts with $j=i,$ not with} \\
& \text{$j=0$ or $j={}$something else, since we're told at} \\
& \text{the outset that $i\le j$.} \\[10pt]
& = e^{-2\lambda} \sum_{j=i}^\infty \frac{\lambda^{j-i}}{(j-i)!} \cdot\frac{\lambda^i}{i!} \\
& \ldots\text{ and now $\lambda^i/(i!)$ does not change as $j$ goes from} \\& \text{$i$ to $\infty,$ so it can be pulled out:} \\[10pt]
= {} & e^{-2\lambda} \frac{\lambda^i}{i!} \sum_{j=i}^\infty \frac{\lambda^{j-i}}{(j-i)!} \\[10pt]
= {} & e^{-2\lambda} \frac{\lambda^i}{i!} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} \text{ where } k = j-i \\[10pt]
= {} & e^{-2\lambda} \frac{\lambda^i}{i!} \cdot e^{\lambda} \\[10pt]
= {} & e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^i}{i!}. \\[15pt]
\text{Therefore } X \sim {} & \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda).
\end{align}

To show that $Y-X\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda),$ first show that the **conditional** distribution of $Y-X$ given $Y$ is the same as the conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y.$ Then that conclusion follows.

It seems regrettable that the exercise didn't have a part $(d)$ in which you show that $X$ and $Y-X$ are actually independent.

Comment: I'm interested in seeing why $X$ and $Y - X$ are independent but I think I'll try it first. Could you expand on that if I'm unable to?

Comment: @SeanRoberson : Probably..... $\qquad$

Comment: @SeanRoberson : By doing things similar to what's done above, you should be able to find their joint distribution.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thank you very much. for (a) and (b) my approach is the same as yours except bad notation and tyros.

Answer (score 1):

Careful, $X, Y$ aren't necessarily independent. Your idea was right though:

$$
P(Y-X = n) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty P(x = k, Y = n + k) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty {n+k\choose k} e^{-2\lambda}  \lambda^{n+k}/(n+k)! \\
=e^{-2\lambda}\lambda^{n}/n! \sum_{k=0}^\infty   \lambda^{k}/k!  = e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{n}/n!\\
$$

But this is just the Poission distribution with parameter $\lambda$.

Comment: Does P(Y-X|Y) = P(X|Y) play a role in calculation?